# Why does adding a test instruction cause a segmentation fault in GNU assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, gnu

I'm having trouble tracking down a segmentation fault. After compiling my c program to assembly, I'm editing it and adding a few things.

I added some code, including this section:

```
.SB1:
         call fib
         jmp     .LBL2
```

That part works fine. But now I want to call test and maybe jump to another label. Right now, I'm just playing with it to see if I can learn how things work (taking baby steps). So I changed the code to this:

```
.SB1:
         call fib
         test    %esp, 0xfffffff
         jz      .SB2
         jmp     .LBL2
.SB2:
         jmp     .LBL2
```

But now I get a segmentation fault. Anyone know why? If you need more information or want the code to reproduce it let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AT&T syntax, a literal needs to be prefixed with `$`. Then, also the operands need to be switched:

```
test    $0xfffffff, %esp
```

Without the `$` prefix, the assembler assumes a memory address, and accessing address `0xfffffff` is most likely out of your mapped memory, which causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I changed the line to `test    %esp, $0xfffffff` and now when I try to compile it, it says: Error: operand type mismatch for `test'